# Restoring a database on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, restore

I am trying to restore a database using the Management Studio GUI, and I am getting the following error.

> The media family on device
>   'F:\xxx.bak' is incorrectly formed.
>   SQL Server cannot process this media
>   family. RESTORE HEADERONLY is
>   terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 3241)

I'm pretty certain this bak file has been used before to restore the database, but the `RESTORE` command was used. Iv looked at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) but am find them a little terse.

Could anyone suggest what the sql might look like for me to successfully restore this db?

Comment: It could be the case of file corruption.

Answer (score 1):

- You can script the task in SSMS, just before clicking the "OK"
- The documentation on [RESTORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) is here, but the basic idea would be `RESTORE DATABASE MyDB FROM DISK = 'F:\xxx.bak'`

However, this error means the file is either corrupt or incomplete. It could be corrupt as part of some FTP or copy process.

One random thought: does the SQL Server account has access to your F: drive? (I don't remember the error if it can't see the file, even if you can in Windows Explorer)

Answer (score 1):

Like gbn says, the error message probably means that the BAK file SQL Server sees is corrupt.  It might be corrupted by the network, or the disks or disk controller that stores the BAK file might have gone bad.

Here's an example restore command:

```
restore database [DatabaseName]
from  disk = N'c:\Restore\RestoreName.bak'
with file = 1,
    move N'DatabaseName_Data' to N'd:\mssql\data\DatabaseName_Data.MDF', 
    move N'DatabaseName_Log' to N'd:\mssql\data\DatabaseName_Log.LDF', 
     replace
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you're backup is corrupt, but to test it, I'd suggest you use the following command:

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY
FROM DISK = 'F:\xxx.bak'
```

That way, if there are issues with the backup file, you can catch them without possibly corrupting your database in the process. But, be warned, VERIFYONLY won't catch all issues, and if the backup was not taken with a CHECKSUM operator, it'll be a header only check of the backup file. Still, it's better than nothing.